# OSXにてPHPをつかう

Tags: php

MacOSからPHPをつかうにはXAMPPとhtmlファイル phpファイル ほかになにが必要ですか？ また XAMPPの下のhtaocsとはなんですか？ふつうに新しくフォルダをつくればいいですか？

Comment: htaocsではなくてhtdocsの間違いですかね？またどの辺りのドキュメントや本を読んでWebの知識の理解を進めていますか？背景がわかればより適切な回答が受けやすいでしょう

Comment: docsです Webの仕組み PHPの起動 辺り です

Comment: Webの仕組みPHPの起動を記述したサイトもしくは本は何ですか、きちんと引用をお願いします